# Finding a word in just a sentence and not in a word (python)

Tags: python

In Python im trying to find a word in a sentece by using:

```
if word in sentence:
    number = number + 1
```

This works fine for finding a word in a sentence, the problem im running into is that this code finds the word inside other words. For example:

```
word = "or"
sentence = "Python or Java use a lot of words"
if word in sentence:
    number = number + 1
```

number will equal 2 instead of 1 because "or" is after "Python" and before "Java", and it also finds "or" in the word "word" Im trying to find a way to find just the word "or" by itself, instead of the program finding it in the sentence and in another word.

Comment: In your example, number will equal 1 and not 2 because `if word in sentence` is true, only once. Without any loop and only one if, you can't have number equal 2.

Comment: For some slightly more advanced stuff see http://stackoverflow.com/q/13913530/2379410

Comment: @Maxime your right, I forgot to add a loop.

Comment: @user2946078 I'd be curious to see what loop you're gonna write. A loop with "if word in [stuff]" won't work as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"Python or Java use a lot of words".lower().split().count('or')
```

should do it.

lower converts all of the text to lower case, split turns it into a list (space is the default delimiter) then count does a count against the list.

Comment: That's actually the only answer that really counts the number of occurrences of the word 'or'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the sentence first using [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> sentence = "Python or Java use a lot of words"
>>> sentence.split()
['Python', 'or', 'Java', 'use', 'a', 'lot', 'of', 'words']
>>>
```

This will give you a list of the words.  After that, your code will work:

```
>>> # I made this so I didn't get a NameError
>>> number = 0
>>> word = "or"
>>> sentence = "Python or Java use a lot of words"
>>> if word in sentence.split():
...     # This is the same as "number = number + 1"
...     number += 1
...
>>> number
1
>>>
```

Comment: Why "number += 1" and not simply `number = 1` ? I can't see how number would equal 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [splitting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) the `sentence` first, as so

```
if word in sentence.split(" "):
```

This will split `sentence` into an array of words, assuming all the words are separated by a single space. This is equivalent to using

```
if word in [ "Python", "or", "Java", "use", "a", "lot", "of", "words" ]:
```

which will check if the whole word exists in the list, rather than checking for substrings in the original `sentence`