# Find all words with a given length in Python

Tags: python, string

I want to make a function that finds all words with a given length, but I can't make it using `re.findall`, because it only works with integers.

This doesn't seem to be working:

```
f = open("wordlist.txt", "r")
line = f.readlines()
a = 14
k = re.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z]{a}\b', ' '.join(line))
r = random.choice(k)
```

Neither this:

```
d = input()
k = re.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z]{d}\b', ' '.join(line))
r = random.choice(k)
```

Both gives:
**IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence**

What could I do?

Comment: You're not actually using your word length in this code. '{a}' doesn't automatically pull in the value of `a`

Comment: What does your file looks like ? You can probably just use  a `line.split() ` and `len(word)`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a regex for that:

```
sentence = "You don't need a regex to get words of length n"
length = 4
print([word for word in sentence.split() if len(word) == length])
# ['need']
```

Comment: Also `filter(lambda word: len(word) == length, sentence.split())`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this list comprehension

```
words = ['apple', 'cat', 'dog', 'banana','ape']
filtered_words = [word for word in words if len(word) == 3]
```

This will only add words of 3 characters in length to the `filtered_words` list.

Answer (score 1):

In case your input file contains symbols like `,`,`.` or any other, you can first filter your file and remove those, then perform filtering:

```
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
symbols = [',', '.', '!', '?']
length = 4

words = "".join([i for i in text if not i in symbols])
words = list(filter(lambda i: len(i)==length,words.split()))
print(words)
```

Output:

```
['amet', 'elit']
```

Answer (score 0):

refer [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913530/python-regular-expression-to-search-for-words-in-a-sentence). seems like the repeated question. Always search before post any repeated question. this post explains clearly about an implementation of the find function.

Also adding an essential part of the answer.

```
In [51]: def find_all_words(words, sentence):
....:     all_words = re.findall(r'\w+', sentence)
....:     words_found = []
....:     for word in words:
....:         if word in all_words:
....:             words_found.append(word)
....:     return words_found

In [52]: print find_all_words(['total', 'staff'], 'The total number of staff in 30?')
['total', 'staff'] 

In [53]: print find_all_words(['total', 'staff'], 'My staff is totally overworked.')
['staff']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it by regex with a length given by input:

```
import re

search_length = input()

# it's 3 brace pairs as two are needed to escape a literal brace in the resulting     
# string and the inner braces for formating with your search_length

pattern = r'\b\w{{{}}}\b'.format(search_length)  
k = re.findall(pattern, ' '.join(line))
```

But as the other answers stated, there are several other ways than regex which might be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.defaultdict` for a dictionary mapping word length to words. The solution below has O(n) complexity.

For multiple counts, this will be more efficient than parsing a sentence each time for each count, yielding O(m*n) complexity.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)

sentence = "You don't need a regex to get words of length n"

for word in sentence.split():
    d[len(word)].add(word)
```

Result:

```
print(d)

defaultdict(set,
            {1: {'a', 'n'},
             2: {'of', 'to'},
             3: {'You', 'get'},
             4: {'need'},
             5: {"don't", 'regex', 'words'},
             6: {'length'}})
```

Then, to access, all words of length 3, use `d[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here a try :

```
l = 14
k = re.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z]{{{}}}\b'.format(l), line)
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `a` was not used in your regular expression.
This will fix the problem:

```
words = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
a = 3
k = re.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z]{%s}\b' % a, ' '.join(words))
print k
```

returns:

```
['foo', 'bar']
```